Problem shape to feature tool in arcgispro while working with R
I am working in ArcGISpro using R.
I am tryig to convert "shapes.txt" from GTFS to shapefile (.shp) using arcpy.conversion.GTFSShapesToFeatures tool and py_run_string package.
Here is my code
RTL_Route <- py_run_string("arcpy.conversion.GTFSShapesToFeatures(r'D:/SadiaChowdhury/Data analysis/Data Cleaning/Transit Routes Final/RTL20240401/shapes.txt', 
              r'D:/SadiaChowdhury/Data analysis/Data Cleaning/Transit RoutesFinal/RTL20240401/RTL_shapes')")

It is showimg me following error:
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) :
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\GTFSShapesToFeatures.py", line 12, in GTFSShapesToFeatures
tool.execute()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\gtfs_shapes_to_features.py", line 304, in execute
self._add_shapes_to_output_table()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\gtfs_shapes_to_features.py", line 238, in _add_shapes_to_output_table
cur.insertRow([shape_id, shape_polyline] + row_to_insert)
RuntimeError: The field is not nullable. [rt_tp_txt]

You could use the {gtfstools} package and the convert_shapes_to_sf() function to convert the shapes table to sf and then use sf::write_sf() to save the result as .shp.
In general terms, something along the lines of:
library(gtfstools)
library(sf)

gtfs <- read_gtfs(<path_to_gtfs>)
sf_shapes <- convert_shapes_to_sf(gtfs)

write_sf(sf_shapes, "shapes.shp")


Thanks for the comment, now shapefile has been created, but the attribute table is not same.
